# result of FusionCharts to excel file

Tags: jquery, excel, charts

I use FusionCharts to create my chart, but I have to export them to excel file. how can I do it. my point is export an excel file from ersult of FusionCharts.

```
            jQuery(window).load(function () {
            var chart1 = new FusionCharts({
                "id":"ChartId1",
                "type": "mscolumn2d",
                "renderAt": "chartdiv21",
                "width": "650",
                "height": "400",
                "dataFormat": "json"
            });

            chart1.setJSONUrl("#{request.contextPath}/faces/report/online.chart?info=20");
            chart1.render("chartdiv21");

            jQuery(this).everyTime(1800000, 'controlled', function () {
                updateChart('ChartId1', '#{request.contextPath}/faces/report/online.chart?info=20');
```

Answer (score 2):

In the JSON data source set through setJSONUrl FusionCharts API method use the attribute **exportEnabled** and set the value as 1.

After rendering the chart the export option would be enabled and select the option export as xls.

Please check the following code snippet.

```
$("#chart-container").insertFusionCharts({
  type: 'mscolumn2d',
  width: '100%',
  id: "mychart",
  height: '450',
  dataFormat: 'json',
  dataSource: {
            "chart": {
                "caption": "Comparison of Quarterly Revenue",
                "xAxisname": "Quarter",
                "yAxisName": "Revenues (In USD)",
                "numberPrefix": "$",
                "plotFillAlpha" : "80",
                                "exportEnabled":"1",
                //Cosmetics
                "paletteColors" : "#0075c2,#1aaf5d",
                "baseFontColor" : "#333333",
                "baseFont" : "Helvetica Neue,Arial",
                "captionFontSize" : "14",
                "subcaptionFontSize" : "14",
                "subcaptionFontBold" : "0",
                "showBorder" : "0",
                "bgColor" : "#ffffff",
                "showShadow" : "0",
                "canvasBgColor" : "#ffffff",
                "canvasBorderAlpha" : "0",
                "divlineAlpha" : "100",
                "divlineColor" : "#999999",
                "divlineThickness" : "1",
                "divLineIsDashed" : "1",
                "divLineDashLen" : "1",
                "divLineGapLen" : "1",
                "usePlotGradientColor" : "0",
                "showplotborder" : "0",
                "valueFontColor" : "#ffffff",
                "placeValuesInside" : "1",
                "showHoverEffect" : "1",
                "rotateValues" : "1",
                "showXAxisLine" : "1",
                "xAxisLineThickness" : "1",
                "xAxisLineColor" : "#999999",
                "showAlternateHGridColor" : "0",
                "legendBgAlpha" : "0",
                "legendBorderAlpha" : "0",
                "legendShadow" : "0",
                "legendItemFontSize" : "10",
                "legendItemFontColor" : "#666666"                
            },
            "categories": [
                {
                    "category": [
                        { "label": "Q1" },
                        { "label": "Q2" },
                        { "label": "Q3" },
                        { "label": "Q4" }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "dataset": [
                {
                    "seriesname": "Previous Year",
                    "data": [
                        { "value": "10000" }, 
                        { "value": "11500" }, 
                        { "value": "12500" }, 
                        { "value": "15000" }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "seriesname": "Current Year",
                    "data": [
                        { "value": "25400" }, 
                        { "value": "29800" }, 
                        { "value": "21800" }, 
                        { "value": "26800" }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "trendlines": [
                {
                    "line": [
                        {
                            "startvalue": "12250",
                            "color": "#0075c2",
                            "displayvalue": "Previous{br}Average",
                            "valueOnRight" : "1",
                            "thickness" : "1",
                            "showBelow" : "1",
                            "tooltext" : "Previous year quarterly target  : $13.5K"
                        },
                        {
                            "startvalue": "25950",
                            "color": "#1aaf5d",
                            "displayvalue": "Current{br}Average",
                            "valueOnRight" : "1",
                            "thickness" : "1",
                            "showBelow" : "1",
                            "tooltext" : "Current year quarterly target  : $23K"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
});
```

Also ensure to add FusionCharts jQuery plugin use the below given CDN link

```
http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.jqueryplugin.js
```